# SDL_DisplayFormat

Tags: c++, image, sdl

why is this simple code not working? its so weird.

```
string f = "pic.bmp";
SDL_Surface * loaded = NULL;
SDL_Surface * optimized = NULL;

loaded = SDL_LoadBMP(f.c_str());

if (loaded != NULL){
    optimized = SDL_DisplayFormat(loaded); // errors here
```

the file compiles, but will not run past there

Comment: Did you called SDL_Init() before calling this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I should make this an answer.

You need to call SDL_Init() first or SDL_DisplayFormat() will not work.

See the [docs](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_DisplayFormat).